# Can the Macbook Pro drive two Ultra HD monitors at 60FPS each?

Tags: display, thunderbolt, displayport

I'm referring to the 2015 Macbook Pro, 15-inch, with the AMD Radeon R9 M370X with 2GB GDDR5 memory. Can this drive two Ultra HD monitors (3840 x 2160) at 60FPS each? If so, would you be able to simultaneously use the built-in display?

To be clear, I'm referring to SST (single-stream transport) monitors, not MST (multi-stream transport).

You'd have to plug each monitor into a Thunderbolt port, since HDMI supports only 30FPS. Are both Thunderbolt ports on different Thunderbolt buses, or the same? In the latter case, there may not be enough bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this document https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204154 The MacBook Pro (15-inch and 17-inch, Early 2011) and later have Thunderbolt2 and can handle two thunderbolt displays (2560x1440).

According to this document https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202856 The MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013 and later) can handle one MST 4K display at 60Hz.

You can run one 4K monitor off of the Thunderbolt display at 60z and a second off HDMI at 30Hz. the two thunderbolt ports are connected. Once you try to connect a second 4K monitor to the other port, you will go over the bandwidth and the second monitor will go dark.

Comment: I clarified the question to say that I'm talking about SST monitors, not MST. Do you have a source for "you will go over bandwidth"? Or is it from personal experience?

Comment: 4K@60Hz is required up to 16Gbps. Thunderbolt2 is comprised of PCIe2.0 and displayport1.2 wrapped into one. The bandwidth of Thunderbolts 2 is 20Gbps. Math... it's a killer.

Comment: Right, I meant to ask: is there a source to back up your claim that both ports are on the same Thunderbolt bus? Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is only one thunderbolt controller for the MacBook Pro

Comment: And one controller means only one bus?

Comment: Bandwidth is limited to the controller not the bus. The only Apple product which will do what you ask is the Mac Pro.

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to get 60 fps at 2560 on my MacBook 13" from 2015.

You should try hacking around in the Terminal with `cscreen`. See:
https://tomachi.co/60fps-2560x1440-resolution-aoc-u2868-macos/

First just type in cscreen at the terminal to get the ID of your monitor, in my case 78ca19c6:

```
cscreen
DisplayID Index Depth Width Height Refresh
78ca19c6 1 32 2560 1440 60
use -h to display all usage options
```

Then issue the command again, this time with the monitor unique ID and the parameters:

```
cscreen -d 32 -x 2560 -y 1440 -r 60 -i 78ca19c6
```

Swap 78ca19c6 for the value of your own monitor.